# How do I run a python script in my robot code and terminate running my python code whenever I want?

Tags: robotframework

This is my robot code, here main.py takes input from events.json(I modify this using robot code) and generates a text file. main.py only stops running when it satisfies a condition, after running it will create a text file and I want to terminate the program and then read the results of text file.But the problem is if i run the below code the test cases are not executing the robotcode keeps on running.

See this

[image]

```
robot framework

*** Settings ***
Library    JSONLibrary
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    Process

*** Variables ***
@{events}   READY_TO_WAIT   STARTING    COMPLETE

*** Test Cases ***
Testcase with correct events and checking final state is DONE
    Testing with correct events events-Create Dict/Convert json to string/create file
    validating state.txt to check if its ending the state with DONE

*** Keywords ***
Testing with correct events events-Create Dict/Convert json to string/create file
    Run Process  ${CURDIR}${/}main.py
    FOR    ${event}     IN      @{events}
        ${new_dict}=    Create Dictionary    event=${event}
        ${json_str1}=   Convert Json To String    ${new_dict}
        Create File    ${CURDIR}${/}events.json     ${json_str1}
    END
    Terminate All Processes
validating state.txt to check if its ending the state with DONE
    ${result}=  Get File    ${CURDIR}${/}state.txt
    Should Be Equal    ${result}    DONE
```

How do I run python scripts and terminate them manually?

Comment: What happens if you use `Start Process` instead of `Run Process`?

Comment: Run process-Log file showing that process completed but its not running main.py, same with start process

Comment: I duplicated you problem: I created main.py with a couple of prints and sleep and started it with `Run Process` like you. I got this error: `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application` In my environment I have to start it with `Run Process  python    ${CURDIR}${/}main.py`